# Conditional file and directory installation in Debian Packages

Tags: debian, shell-script, deb, debian-installer

Is it possible to create a binary Debian package with conditional files and directories installation (e.g. installation of an init script in `/etc/init.d/` after being confirmed by user)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way of doing this in Debian is with [`debconf`](https://wiki.debian.org/debconf) (not to be confused with the Debian conference!). This allows packages to ask questions and act on the user's answers. The wiki linked above has details, including a link to a tutorial (using `debconf` is too involved to explain here).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked just once! I tried different commands to remove and purge the package. But, after re-installation, it uses the old answered value without asking again! Could you please tell me what is the right way to completely cleanup the old answers?

Comment: You need to purge the debconf info when your package is purged (see the documentation; `debhelper` can do this for you). If you really want the question to be shown every time (not recommended), you can clear the "seen" flag on your question. `dpkg-reconfigure` should show the question again as well.